# Removing characters from a String: Regular expression or Manually

Tags: java, regex, string

Which would be a better approach (time and space) for removing characters from a String:

**Approach 1**:

```
String charsToRemove = "abc";
String myString = "abcdef";

myString = myString.replaceAll("["+charsToRemove+"]", "");
```

**Approach 2**:

```
// Initialized to charsToRemove
HashSet<Character> charsToRemoveSet = ...
Character[] myCharArray = myString.toCharArray();


int dst = 0;
for(int src=0; src<myCharArray.length; src++) {
    if(!charsToRemoveSet.contains(myCharArray[src]))
        myCharArray[dst++] = myCharArray[src];
}

myString = new String(myCharArray, 0, dst);
```

Comment: Why don't you just measure it yourself using some profiler and/or microbenchmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visually, option 1 is much clearer. This alone is enough to make me choose it. It's also probably faster, as well (though it depends on the lengths of your input). In option two, you're setting up a second loop. <s>`HashSet.contains()` runs its own loop, adding a second delay.</s>

For short strings, you likely won't notice a difference, but once again, it's hard to tell what's happening in the second.

Comment: `HashSet.contains()` doesn't scan its objects, it calculates the hash value of the input, and building a regex is actually pretty expensive, so it really depends on the size of the input in terms of performance.

Comment: Removed. Still, the main point remains. And yeah, I suppose. Still, readability.

Answer (score 0):

If the character set is fixed then I would change option 1 as

```
private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[abc]");

public String removeChars(String s) {
    return pattern.matcher(s).replaceAll("");
}
```

String.replaceAll looks nice but internally it calls Pattern.compile each time. Besides `"[" + charsToRemove + "]"` is a performance killer which in our case can be avoided.

as for option 2

```
Character[] myCharArray = myString.toCharArray();
```

won't work, it should be

```
char[] myCharArray = myString.toCharArray();
```